# How to set an expiration date for Firestore documents

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

How can I add a future date and time to a firestore document and add a function when that time expires? For example today I create a document and record that time and then I want to register that fifteen days later the `publicado` field will be `false`. It's possible?

I am creating a document in firestore in the following way:

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseService } from '../../../services/firebase.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

forma: FormGroup;

constructor( fb: FormBuilder, private fs: FirebaseService ) {
  this.forma = fb.group ({
    fechaCreacion: [ firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() ],
    publicado: [ true ],
  })
}

agregarAviso() {
  this.fs.addAviso(this.forma.value);
}
```

**firebase.service.ts**

```
constructor( private afs: AngularFirestore ) {}

addAviso(aviso){
  this.afs.collection('avisos').add(aviso);
}
```

As a result I get the following:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Firestore doesn't have a concept of a TTL (time to live) for documents.  Documents exist forever until some code directly deletes them.

You could write some code to periodically query for documents that should be expired, and you will have to accept that they may finally be deleted *after* the timestamp, by up to the amount of time your process runs periodically.  You will likely want to run this on a backend you control, with a scheduler that you control, using the Firebase Admin SDK.

Comment: Okay. I think I have not raised my approach well. What I try is not to delete the document but rather to update it. So for example is it possible to update the `published` field to` false` after some time? This is what I do now to update it at that moment: html `(ngModelChange) =" updatePublicated (warning.id, warning, $ event)"` ts: `updatePublicated (key, obj, e) {
     this.fs.updatePosted (key, e);
   }`

Comment: service: `updatePublicated (key, published) {
     this.afs.doc ('warnings /' + key) .update ({published});
   }

Comment: There is no scheduled work at all in Firestore.  You still have to do what I'm suggesting in my answer.